# Zpanel on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, zpanel

I am installing zPanel with 'wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/beta/Ubuntu-14_04-LTS/ubuntu-14.04-LTS-apache2.4.9-php5.5.14.sh " I'm stuck at "enter your MySQL root password" I installed the same zpanel on the same server like six months ago and everything was fine I installed it successfully, but I do not know what's going on now ... I do not get this message before

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Aa1c.png)

What should I do?
THANKS!

Comment: You should enter your MySQL root password.

Comment: But I can´t... It shows that message over and over... as you can see on image and also I don´t know root mysql password

Comment: Maybe a very good idea is for you not to install software on your server that is **beta** (which means *not ready for real use yet*) unless you know what you're doing and how to resolve problems you run into.